# Loading Script globally on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that features some sort of plugin that requires a 30-line script.
Such plugin is present throughout the site pages (well, by now there are just two), because it is part of the header, which is also identical.

I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid executing that 30-line-long script every time I change from a page to the next, since the header is identical, thus improving loading time. (If you say 30 lines of code is nothing for a browser, then my question will be answered)

Comment: Depends what the 30 lines are! It could be inconsequential or very expensive to run it (e.g. iterating over a large set may not be much code, but can take up lots of CPU time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, the script will be cached by the browser and won't be downloaded again. About 30 lines of code being a lot or not: depends on what those lines do! It's possible to write extremely expensive code with only a few lines, or even a one-liner.

Comment: This. But also I might add for the OP's benefit that even though the _source_ is cached, it will _execute_ every page load (as the execution context is not persisted between pages, even on the same website). If you want to persist the state of the JavaScript, consider loading pages via ajax and using the History API

Comment: Thank you BLSully. I actually have a site which loads with ajax, but I had the problem that you can't link to content on the website example.com, since you always are at example.com/#

bfavaretto said the script is cached, and 30 lines of code may not be much, so by now I don't worry.

Thank you both very much!

Comment: @Nico Just to clarify, when I say it's cached, I mean it doesn't have to be downloaded again, but it has to be executed (from cache) on every page load. That is not the case if the whole site is ajax-driven, but that comes with its own share of issues, as you probably noticed already.